# sql query to find sum with where

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a database table which looks like its shown below :

```
Date      Store SubStore ProductsSold
2013-03-01    A      AA          33
2013-03-01    B      BB          53 
2013-03-01    C      CC          43 
2013-03-01    B      BB          11 
2013-03-01    A      AA          65 
2013-03-01    A      DD          65
```

The table has no primary key or foreign keys.

I would like to write one query for my report where I would like to see the Products sold 
for substores AA, CC and rest all under Others for the Month of March.

Something like this :

```
Substore    ProductsSold
AA               343
CC               332
Others           3432
```

Is there a way I can do it ?

I came up with a query something like this :

```
Select SubStore,  Sum(NumberOfProducts) as Sales
 from 
[dbo].[TableName]
where [Year] = year(@ParamDate) AND [Month] = month(@ParamDate)
and (SubStore = 'AA' or SubStore =  'BB')
```

Please let me know what changes I can make So that I can also see the others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` to create a value for the store name that you can group on:

```
select
  case when Substore in ('AA','CC') then Substore else 'Others' end as SubStore,
  Sum(ProductsSold) as ProductsSold
from
  [dbo].[TableName]
where
  [Year] = year(@ParamDate) AND [Month] = month(@ParamDate)
group by
  case when Substore in ('AA','CC') then Substore else 'Others' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing I could think of -

```
select t.substore, 
SUM(productsSold) as productsSold
from tablename as t
where t.substore in ('AA', 'CC')
group by substore
UNION ALL
select 'Others' as substore, 
SUM(productsSold) as productsSold
from tablename as t
where t.substore not in ('AA', 'CC')
```